# How do you mount a rw APFS volume in / on Big Sur Beta 3

Tags: macos, beta, big-sur

1. Create a mount point in `/etc/synthetic.conf`, e.g. /Foo
2. Create a new APFS volume
3. ???

Previously you could mount as rw via FSTAB.

```
UUID=<FOO_UUID> /Foo apfs rw
```

This no longer works in Beta 3.

Any help, much appreciated.